# add a "add to cart" feature using mongodb and node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying many things and couldn't write the code for the "add to cart" feature. Can you please help me in doing this?

Here is the cart model:

```
var cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'User'},
totalPrice: {type: Number, default: 0},
items: [{
    item: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'Product'},
    qty: {type: Number, default: 1},
    price: {type: Number, default: 0}
}]})
```

Here is the product model:

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
category: String,
name: String,
price: Number,
image: String,
description: String,
stock: Number,
reviews: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'Review'
    }
]
})
```

Edit(detailed explanation):

step1: when I click on the add to cart button it should make a "get" request and these following things should happen:

- get the id of the signed-in user i.e req.user._id
- store the clicked product inside the items array in the cart model
- based on the required quantity of the product it should calculate the price i.e qty*price and store it in "price" in the items array in the cart model

step2: when another product is added to the cart it should follow all the steps mentioned in step1 and in addition to that it should calculate the total price of the cart i.e. ***totalPrice = qty1xproduct1_price + qty2xproduct2_price + ....*** and store it in "totalPrice" in the cart model.

step3: when I click on view cart i.e. router.get("/cart"), this should take me to the cart and it should check for the signed-in user and show the cart which belongs to that user i.e. it should check for ***Cart.owner*** and show me all the details of the cart. Ex: (

1. product details in short
2. quantity
3. price= qty x price_per_product
4. In the end total price of all these products

)

***edit 3:***

Here is add to cart button:

```
<form action="/product/<%= product._id %>/addCart" method="POST">
            <select name="quantity">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            <button>Add to cart</button>
            </form>
```

Here is cart route:

```
router.post("/product/:id/addCart", async (req, res) => {
const quantity = req.body;
Product.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundProduct){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    const product = {
        item: foundProduct._id,
        qty: quantity,
        price: foundProduct.price * quantity 
    }
    Cart.owner = req.user._id;
    Cart.itmes.push(product);
    Cart.save();
    res.redirect("/cart");
})
})

router.get("/cart", function(req, res){
    Cart.find({owner: req.user._id}, function(err, userCart){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        const pPrice = userCart.items.map(p => p.price);
        const totalPrice = pPrice.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        userCart.totalPrice = totalPrice;
        userCart.save()
        res.render("cart", {cart: userCart});
    })
})
```

It shows `Cannot POST /product/5f80569156202d0a624d35af/addCart`

Comment: `res.redirect("/cart")` ?

Comment: Yes Res.redirect("/cart")

Comment: Problem solved then :)

Comment: Can you explain it?!

Comment: Well, you asked `It would redirect to "/cart" after adding the product`, here you go. `res.redirect("/cart")`, that's the answer

Comment: No my question is I want the logic for adding a product to the cart when I click on "add to cart".

Comment: ? But that's just creating a Mongoose object and saving it to the database. Any tutorial will tell you how to do this. Google gave me [this](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-use-mongoose-save-1419)

Comment: I can do that. The problem is I want the total price in the cart change automatically and I'm not able to do that.

Comment: So this is yet another problem. Nothing in the code you posted or your original question explains that. I have to ask questions myself, make suggestions, you say that's not it, so I suggest something else, then you say the problem is yet something else... Right now I still have no clue what your exact problem is. Please, edit your question and describe your problem precisely. Step 1, step 2, step 3. [Create a minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi!, I have edited the question. I hope it helps now.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, but I'm afraid this doesn't help. You only wrote what you want your application to do, you didn't provide the relevant code. Where is your button (HTML code)? Where is the form, the ajax request (Javascript code)? Where exactly are you stuck in the process, is it when the Ajax call is made, you pass data, but the server doesn't receive it?

Comment: How can I send you the link to my project?

Comment: Uh, why do you want to send me the link to your project? Stackoverflow is a platform to help people with their code, you can post the relevant code here :/

Comment: I have added the code you've asked for and tell me if you need anything else. And sorry if I'm bothering you, I'm new to programming and this my college project and I have to submit this within this month.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah now you're talking! :D So now I understand the real problem at last! You have a `<select>` element, you pick a value, and then you click a button. All you want to do is, when the button is clicked, read the selected value, that's it! Well that's very simple, there are plenty of tutorials for this, for instance this one : https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/selected.php

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped!! But what about the cart route and the query I've mentioned?

Comment: Well that's pretty much it, isn't it? After you read the value from the `<select>` you can do `location.href='/product/' + value + '/addCart'`. Then you'll get this value in Node with the `:id` parameter, then you can use it to do whatever you want in Mongo :)

Comment: The problem here is that you need someone to write the entire thing : you don't know how to rerad a quantity, you don't know how to create a new product, how to sum up the price of several products, etc. Sorry but I can't write your whole application :) However I did post an answer with code samples that, I hope, will guide you.

Comment: Hey I have written most of the code, but there is a problem, it shows cannot POST /product/5f80569156202d0a624d35af/addCart. I have mentioned the code in edit 3.

Comment: Ha, that's a new problem. I think this thread is way too long already :) You should open a new question. But start with checking your consoles (Node + browser)

Comment: Hey can you help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388457/caught-an-error-while-pushing-a-product-to-cart-typeerror-cannot-read-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to help you, here's a quick example :

Simple HTML :

```
Quantity :
<select id="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button id="btnOK">OK</button>
```

In your front-end JS (I used jQuery because it's much simpler to write than plain JS) :

```
$("#btnOK").click( () => {

    const quantity = Number( $("#quantity").val());

    const productData = {
        id : "123456",
        quantity,
        price : quantity * 20
    }

    $.post( "/product" , productData, result => {
        console.log("Response from Node : ", result)
    })
})
```

In your back-end JS :

```
router.post("/product", async (req, res) => {
    const productData = req.body;
    const result = await (new productModel(productData)).save();
    res.send(result)
})
```

If you want to return the sum of the price of several items, you don't need an aggregation. You can just fetch the products and sum up their prices. For instance :

```
const idArray = ["1", "3", "18", "27"]

// This should return 4 products :
const products = await productModel.find({
        _id: {
            $in: idArray
        }
    })
    .lean()
    .exec()
    
const totalPrice = products
                    .map( p => p.price)
                    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

res.send(totalPrice)
```