# Caught an error while pushing a product to cart. TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to push the product details into the cart model when a user clicks on "add to cart" button on a particular product. But it shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Here is the route file:

```
var express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router(),
    Product = require("../models/Product"),
    Cart = require("../models/Cart");

router.post("/product/:id/addCart", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
 const quantity = req.body.quantity;
let cart = new Cart();
Product.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundProduct){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    const product = {
        item: foundProduct._id,
        qty: quantity,
        price: foundProduct.price * quantity 
    }
    var totalPrice = 0;
    totalPrice = totalPrice + product.price;
    console.log(req.user._id);
    cart.owner = req.user._id;
    cart.items.push(product);
    cart.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    cart.save();
    console.log(cart);
    res.redirect("/cart");
})  
})
```

This is the cart model:

```
var cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'User'},
items: [{
    item: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'Product'},
    qty: {type: Number, default: 1},
    price: {type: Number, default: 0}
}]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Cart", cartSchema);
```

Comment: `Cart` is not defined... is it? `req.user` is also undefined... is it?

Comment: Cart and req.user are defined. I can see the "_id" in req.user but still, it shows req.user._id is undefined n I don't know why.

Comment: But where are they defined? Not in the code above

Comment: Cart is defined above this code and req.user comes with the express.js

Comment: But instead of describing the relevant code, why don't you just post it? Alright, `Cart` is defined, but `Cart.items` is not (because the error says exactly this). This is the part of the code we need to see

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question. You can see I have required the cart model, but `Cart.items` comes under the `Cart` model. So how is it not defined?

Comment: You defined the schema, not the model. You didn't do `cartModel = mongoose.model("cart", cartSchema)`. And then you didn't create a new Mongoose object with `let cart = new cartModel()` so then you can do `cart.items.push(...)` Read some doc : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But if I make `let cart = new Cart()`, it makes a new object every time I click on the "add to cart" button and it doesn't push the item in the existing cart. You can see the code.

Comment: Use `foundProduct` then. Your problem is not a bug or a typo. It's elaborating your application's logic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in "items" collection. Try with

`Cart.items.push(product);`

instead

`Cart.itmes.push(product);`

Comment: I have corrected the typo but it still shows the same error